# Bluetooth bugs out when I turn it off/back on again

Tags: gnome, bluetooth

After I turn bluetooth off and back on again, available bluetooth devices don't show up and the Gnome system tray reports it as off, but gives the option to turn it off as if it were on:

[image: screenshot of this happening]

Settings also shows the switch in the "on" state, but no bluetooth devices appear to connect to:

[image: another example of this]

I found that closing and re-opening settings fixes this, but it's still really annoying.

Edit: So sorry I forgot to add this, I'm running Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: I have the same on Ubuntu 20.10 but that's a different story. What are you running? If you are on Ubunti open a terminal and type `lsb_release -a` then add that to your question to get some help from the community.

Comment: @darth_epoxy just did, thanks for reminding me!